# Synonym for "part of the sentence"

Tags: synonyms

I'm referring to a very long sentence while explaining it, and I end up saying:
The adjective used in the first part of the sentence...; The second part of the sentence uses...; As for the third part of the sentence...

Is there a nice way to be less repetitive, while saying the same?

Comment: Check out *clause*.

Comment: So you'd say "part of the clause" instead. Thanks.

Comment: No a clause is a technical term, a sentence is comprised of clauses, if you can spot the clauses, you can refer to the clause instead of "the part of the sentence" ; see (1) here https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clause

Comment: Ohhh I see now.

Comment: Could you give us an example sentence that you might be talking about and an example sentence that you might want to use in describing it, please? (It'll make it much easier to help you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a long sentence you can refer to parts of the sentence.  Long sentences usually have a dependant clause and an independent clause.  The dependant clause cannot make a sentence by itself.  You can't end it with a period and also make sense. The independent clause will make sense if you were to put a period at the end of it.  So the distinction of clauses which part of the sentence you refer to for the reader to follow.